# If both $f \ge 1$ and $f\le 1 $ almost surely then $f = 1_A$, where $A$ is borel

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive measurable function. If $f\leq 1$ almost surely and $f\geq 1$ almost surely (with respect to lebesgue measure). Show that $f=1_{A}$ for some $A\in B[0,1]$.

I'm not sure how to start.

My attempt is as follows:

So $f\geq 1$ almost surely means there exists some set U in borel algebra on [0,1] such that $\mu(U)=0$ on which $f<1$

$f\leq 1$ almost surely means that there exists some set V in borel algebra on [0,1] such that $\mu(V)=0$ on which $f>1$

By construction of U and V, $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Hence, setting $A=U\cup V$, we obtain

However, I have gotten nowhere.

May someone elaborate? What should I modify the problem for the conclusion to hold (if it doesnt hold?)

Answer (score 1):

There exist sets $E,F$ of measure $0$ such that $f(x) \leq 1$ if $x \notin E$ and $f(x) \geq 1$ if $x \notin F$. Let $A=E \cup F$. Then $A$ has measure $0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \notin A$ (because $x \notin A$ implies $x \notin E$ and $x \notin F$). Now let $D=\{x: f(x)=1\}$. Then $D$ is a Lebesgue measurable set and  $f=1_D$ almost everywhere. To complete the proof just note that there is a  Borel set $B$ such that $I_D=I_B$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @orientablesurface I used $E,F$ and $A$ to show that $f=1$ almost everywhere. Once this is done it follows immediately that $f=I_D$  almost everywhere where $D=\{x: f(x)=1\}$.

Comment: and D is simply the complement of A, right?

Comment: @orientablesurface Yes, we can take $E=\{x: f(x) >1\}, F=\{x: f(x) <1\}$ and $A =E \cup F$ so $D$ becomes the complement of $A$.